# java.nio.file organizing text from a file

Tags: java, text, java.nio.file

I have never really worked with text files in java before, but now I need to and I am sort of stuck. Below is what I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path file = Paths.get("dir/NRCLexiconEmotion.txt");

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }

}
```

and this is part of the output

```
virtual anger   0
virtual anticipation    0
virtual disgust 0
virtual fear    0
virtual joy 0
virtual negative    0
virtual positive    0
virtual sadness 0
virtual surprise    0
virtual trust   0
```

I am trying to copy the word and then I am going to create a serial number for the word using the numbers. So I need to be able to read the word then the emotion and then the number matched to the emotion.

I tried using line.charAt(); and when I put an index number in I just get an error. I think what is causing me troubles is I don't know a lot about streams. I can't seem to find a specific method for my need in the java docs and was wondering if someone could help me out.

if it helps or anyone is interested I am wanting to match songs to certain moods based on the lyrics of the songs, tags and genres. So I will be working with a lot of text files.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class?

Comment: Are you looking just to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the line into a three value array?

Comment: Why are you afraid of streams in this particular case? There is not a single of them in your code. You have a line as `String,` have a look at [`String.split(...).`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

BTW, `charset` can be simplified to [`StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).